# ID3DX11EffectShaderResourceVariable::SetResource(NULL) can't unbind resources

Tags: directx, directx-11

The problem happened when I tried to implement exercise 4 in chapter 12 in Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11. In my code I tried to bind a SRV of a texture to `Texture2D` in *.fx* code. After that, I used:

```
Effects::BasicFX->SetDiffuseMap(NULL);
```

to unbind the resource, but it seems that it didn't do the work. I had to add:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* srvs[] = { NULL };
dc->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, srvs);
```

or the debug output kept warning me as follows:

```
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets: Resource being set to OM RenderTarget slot 0 is still bound on input! [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #9: DEVICE_OMSETRENDERTARGETS_HAZARD]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets[AndUnorderedAccessViews]: Forcing PS shader resource slot 0 to NULL. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #7: DEVICE_PSSETSHADERRESOURCES_HAZARD]
```

This situation also happened when I was working with Compute Shader. I had to use:

```
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* uavs[] = { NULL };
UINT initCounts[] = { -1 };
dc->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, uavs, initCounts);

ID3D11ShaderResourceView* srvs[] = { NULL };
dc->CSSetShaderResources(0, 1, srvs);
```

to unbind the `Texture2D` and `RWTexture2D` in my shader code instead of using just `ID3DX11EffectShaderResourceVariable::SetResource(NULL)` and `ID3DX11EffectUnorderedAccessViewVariable::SetUnorderedAccessView(NULL)`.

Can someone tell what might be wrong with my code or confirm this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetDiffuseMap` isn't a Effects 11 method, so I don't know what it is doing, but I'm going to assume it calls `SetResource` at some point.

Effects 11 doesn't change anything on the device until you call `Apply`, so calling a set method isn't going to change any binding on the device.

Effects 11 by design is lazy about changing state for performance so in the cases of these hazard warnings, explicitly unbinding as you are doing is in fact the correct solution.

Be sure to use the latest version of Effects 11 which is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2015). The copy that came with Frank's book is quite old. For some notes on the differences, see the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki/Effects-11) and the project Readme.

> Note that while that book is still quite useful and relevant, it makes heavy use of support libraries from the legacy DirectX SDK. You can and should avoid using the legacy DirectX SDK for Direct3D 11 or later. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/), [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-), and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification. And can you tell me what might be able to crash the graphic debugger in visual studio 2015 ? Capturing Frame works fine but whenever I try to open a frame, it crashes. Also the debugger works on other project so i know there's something wrong with my code but I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: The debugger says something like "The Graphics Diagnostics engine has encountered a fatal error. Please try to reopen the document again, and if the problem persists, please contact the support team."